# ¿Por qué no funciona correctamente esta fórmula en Excel?

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, office365

¿Por qué no me funciona `setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B4;"x";B6)")`?

Intente Varias Formas pero no me ejecuta el codigo quiero que me reemplace el caracter de `X` por un valor de la casilla numérica ya escrita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Error de setFormula al ejecutar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Quiero Reemplazar el caracter `x` que esta en la celda B4 y que se sustituya ya sea por la celda B5 o B6 y que se me imprima en una celda cualquiera pero me da el error al usar el comando substitute en el Script

en mi codigo utilicé el siguiente codigo:

```
workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("B8").setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B4;'x';B6)")
```

> Range setFormula: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.

Me sale ese Error Ya intente Otras Maneras y no me funciona

Y quiero que me de como resultado lo que esta en la celda B9 pero no logro hacerlo con el script

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola. Aquí son más de hacer cargamontón cuando alguien no conoce el uso del foro, así que sugiero, además de leer las reglas para publicar, que elimines las que has colocado como "respuestas" y que en esta misma "Pregunta" uses la opción de "Editar" y modifiques/mejores tu pregunta para que así se te entienda y recibas la ayuda respectiva. No olvides detalles como por ejemplo ¿Estás intentando insertar una fórmula o en realidad lo que quieres es su resultado? Saludos.

Comment: Posiblemente sea porque debes escapar las comillas dentro de la fórmula :) Si el laburo me deja, más tarde paso a ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigo creyendo que "algo" quedó sin mencionarse, pero suponiendo que simplemente quieres insertar esa fórmula en alguna celda, mira cómo se haría para hacerlo en, por ejemplo, B8:

```
workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange("B8").setFormula("=SUBSTITUTE(B4,\"x\",B6)");
```

No te olvides que para TypeScript el separador universal de lista/argumento, siempre es la coma excepto si se usa SetFormulaLocal en que se debe usar la de tu sistema operativo y/o web, dando error si no coincide, por eso es mejor usar SetFormula. Ah, otra cosa, en el caso de las fórmulas, los textos no se insertan tal cual, en VBA, mira bien cómo he hecho. Saludos.